# Убрать себя из списка fail2ban

Tags: безопасность

Заходил через ssh ввел не правильно пароль 3 раза попал в бан на 3 часа...

Есть доступ к файлам через ISP Manager.

Вопросы:

- Возможно через какой-то фаил убрать себя из бана?
- Возможно ли добавить свой ip в список доверенных чтоб его не банил fail2ban?
- Возможно ли чужой ip который стучится уже больше месяца забанить навсегда вручную? Или создать правило более 10 банов за месяц бан навсегда?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Белый список [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Whitelist):

#### Это правило будет игнорировать соеденения из частных сетей.

> ignoreip = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16

Поставьте подсеть из которой вы хотите попадать на сервер. И также рекомендую добавить один надёжный ip что если кого-то из разрешённых подсетей заблокирует, вы могли зайти на сервер и не ждать бана.

Answer (score 3):

про игнорирование ip в предыдущем посте есть. А вот заблокировать надолго существует параметр bantime. Кроме того есть такая штука как [recidive]. Если после того как прошло время опять стучатся, то при включенном recidive он с первого же раза опять надолго банится

Comment: И incremental: https://habrahabr.ru/post/238303/